# How to show the message “No Products” when there's no products in my custom block?

Tags: html, static, block, frontend, magento-1.9

I need to show the message "No Products" or "There are no products matching the selection" when there's nothing to show in my block.

```
    <?php        
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

foreach ($productCollection as $_product)
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>" width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>

<div class="product-details">
<p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>

<?php   
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){?>
<div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
<?php }

else if ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
<div>by eBay</div>
<?php }

else { ?>
<div>by Home Done</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also I need to add getPriceHtml to the above code to show the product price.

I have tried `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

There you go:
(Advice: use closed tags like `<?php if(): ?>` for better readability)

```
<?php if(is_array($productCollection) && count($productCollection) ): ?>
    <?php foreach ($productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>" width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
        <div class="product-details">
            <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>
        <?php $merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name'); ?>
        <?php if ($merchant_name):?>
            <div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
        <?php elseif($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()): ?>
            <div>by eBay</div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div>by Home Done</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
// here goes whatever you want to display if no products found in list  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have added your code like this https://jsfiddle.net/fhp3uvbu/ , but I am getting NO PRODUCTS message even I have few products in the attribute "getMerchantName"

Comment: @user6036056 You cannot actually run your PHP on this jsfiddle.. it's not designed to interpret PHP that way. Your best shot is to start debugging. Put `echo "functionName started"` or `print_r(array())` when Object or Array at every beginning and end (before the return, break or exception) of a called function in your script. Check how deep the error tracing will take you, you should know what is causing this to not work.